# Method not fired in UICollectionView when added within a UIStackview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uistackview

I have added a `UICollectionVIew` to a `vertical Stack View`. I connected both `datasource` and `Delegate` from `storyboard` and added the `delegate/datasource` from the code as well.

However, the following method is not being called at all:

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { ... }
```

But, the methods

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }
```

are being called.

So, I moved the `UICollectionVIew` out of the `vertical Stack View` and it was working then. But, the method is not being called when the `UICollectionVIew` is in the `vertical Stack View`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with the UIStackview, if you move the collectionView out of the stackView, does the problem still exists?

Comment: @AymanIbrahim It works when i move it out.

Comment: @IIIep
I have just tried putting a collection view inside a UIStackview, and it works.
it will be helpful if you can share with us the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Same happen  with  me in past with `TableView` but not with `UIStackView`

If `numberOfSections` and  `numberOfItemsInSection` called and `cellForItemAt`  not called then only possible reason your `CollectionView` height is 0

Because  of that your cell didn't get enough space to show  cell

You can Check same thing by adding height of your collection view to 0
in to the case where you said  **I moved the UICollectionVIew out of the vertical Stack View and it was working then.**